# Leaky faucet, how to disassemble this valve?

Tags: plumbing, faucet, valve, leaking

I have a leaky faucet (only hot water is leaking). I turned off the supply and managed to remove the outer covers. It looks like this:

[image]

However, I can't figure out how to disassemble further to actually fix the leak.

Here is the valve close-up:

[image]

The obvious point is the hexagonal fitting. But if I apply torque, the whole piping starts to move and I do not want to risk that it cracks at the source.

My common sense would tell me to use use a pipe wrench one hand hand and an adjustable wrench (matching the hexagonal fitting) on the other hand and apply torque in opposite directions. But I do not find a spot to apply the pipe wrench.

How can I disassembly and fix this valve?

Comment: remove all of the grime and  look at it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start with spraying some kind of penetrating oil like pb blaster.

If you can figure out the thread then you should be able to get two nuts and form a lock nut on the wider thread.

Once you have your lock nut you should be able to turn the two against each other.

Comment: I have not tried this yet but marking a solution for now. I am trying to find proper nuts (inner diameter is exactly 1”) and get pb blaster.

Comment: I'd guess the nuts would be 1" MIP threaded.  So something like a 1" FIP nut.  https://bkproducts.com/1-in-fip-black-iron-lock-nut

Comment: The other surgery technique would be to use an abrasive disc to cut a relief in the nut you can't remove and then use a flat screw driver to split it apart.  Downside is then you have to find a new nut or replace this flanged nut with a washer and a nut.  Can also be quite hard to get a grinder or cut off tool into that space.  There are diablo reciprocating blades that can cut cast.  A nut splitter might also be able to work.  Are you replacing the cartridge once you remove it or trying to repair it?

Comment: Happy to report, eventually got it working! I could not find the same locknut unfortunately. But I borrowed another plastic one from the cold tap and turned them against each other. Also applied PB plaster generously and eventually it gave in :)

Comment: That's great !  Thanks for the update !

Answer (score 1):

You may have to remove the red nut that holds the valve body to the sink.

Then remove the entire body from the sink and place it in a vice or use slip joint pliers to hold the body and remove the hex nut.

Alternatively, you could try the slip joint pliers above the red nut while the valve is in the sink.  However you may damage the threads and re-installing the covers could be problematic.

Comment: I was able to remove the red nut but the problem is it's connected behind the sink with a solid metal pipe. So I can't remove the while thing from the sink :-(

Comment: I have also tried putting the slip joint pliers on the threads while applying opposite torque onto the hex-nut. But it doesn't move a thing and the slip joint pliers just slip. Is there any way to loosen the connection or so?

Comment: You can try a little heat to the hex-nut, and squeeze the slip plies harder. There is no magic...sometimes the repair is harder and more time consuming than just replacing the entire faucet.

Comment: Thank you. I am afraid this may be the case in the end but do not want to give up yet. One more followup question: I tried wrapping a cloth in between the slip plies and the threads to protect them but it just slips too much. Is there any better stuff to put in between? That protects threads on one hand (allowing me to grip hard) but is very unslippery on the other?

Comment: try some rubber. I have heard of folks trying rubber bands...never tried it myself.

Comment: you can try some pb blaster to penetrate and loose up the pieces.

Comment: "Solid metal pipe" being a piece of rigid supply line?