# How to fix dripping faucet after disassembling valve?

Tags: plumbing, faucet, valve, plumbing-fixture, leaking

This is my followup question from [Leaky faucet, how to disassemble this valve?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/292710/leaky-faucet-how-to-disassemble-this-valve/292738) which I was finally able to disassemble. However, now my question is, what made this "leaky" and dripping? How can I fix it?

[image]

I am starting by putting all small parts apart and cleaning them but I assume this is not enough?

Comment: Usually one would replace all (formerly) soft seals, gaskets & o-rings, while cleaning (without scratching) any metal pieces.

Comment: I have re-assembled it (after soaking in vinegar) but it still leaks :-( Actually, it leaks even more. Ideally I'd just replace the entire catridge but I can't find it anywhere. I don't know which year, brand etc this is. Can this be salvaged without replacing the ENTIRE SINK (which would be unacceptable)? For example, if I replace the seals, gaskets, o-rings, how could I get the proper ones? I looked for "faucet repair kit" at big box store (HomeDepot) but not sure which would even be the right one...

Comment: Usually one doesn't replace the _sink_ if the _faucet_ it dripping... You can replace the whole faucet assembly if necessary. It just so happened that the wife & I liked PricePfister faucets when we went looking, but that replacement parts for them seemed to be almost impossible to find at reasonable prices in our neck o'the woods. We ended up replacing the whole faucet. With another PP one. Did that twice, IIRC, before we finally found one we liked in a different brand...

Comment: If there are any o-rings that seal the faucet, you should be able to pick up a variety pack of replacements (different sizes & thicknesses) for only a few bucks and replace _all_ the o-rings. Or, take the ring & cartridge with you to the store and do some sizing there, then pick up a pack of the correct size. Still only a couple of bucks.

Comment: Your best option is to just replace (both) valves with different model

Comment: Thanks, I will try with a variety pack first (gasket & o-ring). If replacing both valves, apologize my ignorant question, but what am I even looking for? Would you have an example of what I'd need to purchase? If I replace the valve, the handle doesn't fit any more. And how do I make sure that the valve fits in the hold in the faucet? Or are these standardized?